# how to test (unit test) the android ui and how to test(functional test) the same android ui using the junit framework in eclipse

Tags: android, unit-testing, user-interface, junit, functional-testing

i had tested the ui of the android applications .the output is success one. the test automatically assign and calculate the things for the calculator activity.but ,iam confusing now ,what is unit test and functional test .if anybody knows about this.pls point me to do what do u know

Answer (score 1):

Unit Testing : Its a Software testing process done for a smallest testable parts in a screen

Functional Testing : See if all the fields(including non mandatory fields) are functioning correctly